# Trying to display images with PIL and BytesIO but returns nothing

Tags: python, image, png, bytesio

I'm trying to display the logos from a dataset. 
The dataset looks like this:

```
Player      Club Logo        
tom         https://abc.png
jerry       https://def.png
peter       https://frf.png
woody       https://awt.png
```

However, it didnt return me any logos. All it did show was 4 empty grid boxes. My code is below. 
I also did try to use `im = Image.open(BytesIO(r.content)).show()` but the logos ended up opening on my computer instead.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import requests

from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(2,2))

for i in range(4):
    r = requests.get(df['Club Logo'][i])
    im = Image.open(BytesIO(r.content))

plt.show()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with these images:

`"0.png"`:

[image]

`"1.png"`:

[image]

`"2.png"`:

[image]

`"3.png"`:

[image]

I think you want this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(2,2))

for i in range(4): 
    # Load image and make into Numpy array
    im = Image.open(f'{i}.png').convert('RGB') 
    na = np.array(im) 
    # Shove into the plot
    ax[i%2][i//2].imshow(na) 

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: hi Mark thanks for your help! I'm just wondering for this line    im = Image.open(f'{i}.png').convert('RGB')... does the f{i} mean a file? i did try it but it returned me with [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '0.png'.

Comment: i used this "im = Image.open(BytesIO(r.content)).convert('RGB')" and managed to get 3 out of 4 pictures with 1 grid still black though.

Comment: That's likely something to do with your URLs. My point is that your initial code is missing the two lines `na = np.array(im) ` and `ax[i%2][i//2].imshow(na)` which actually put the images into the plot.